# Bitwise AND on hexadecimal numbers in linux shell script to give output in hexadecimal number

Tags: linux, shell, bit-manipulation, bitwise-and

I have two hexadecimal numbers and I want to perform BITWISE AND on them. The primary requirement is I want the o/p in hexadecimal form
I do something like below

```
$line=0xC01234567C012345

$filter=0x07ffffff0fffffff 

echo $((16#$line&16#$filter))

expected output: 0x001234560c012345
```

I am getting the output in decimal format.
Besides, I am performing the above bitwise AND on all the entries in a file using the while loop. 
How to do that correctly?

I try awk also to get bitwise AND for hexadecimal numbers. It works fine but only for static value but it's not working when I gave the file as input.

```
My code:
    awk '
        BEGIN {
           printf "(%d AND %d) = %d\n", 0xA0, 0x6, and(0xA0, 0x6)
        }
        {printf "(%x AND %x) = %d\n", $0, num2, and(num1, num2)}
        END{
           printf "(%d AND %d) = %d\n", 0xB0, 0x6, and(0xB0, 0x6)
        }
' $path/tmp3.txt
```

Data inside tmp3.txt is as below

```
0xc00c16b0b711d202
0xc00c16b4b711d20a
0xc00c16b8b711d212
0xc00c16bc7711d21a
0xc00c16c07711d224
0xc00c16d07711d244
```

The output which I am getting is as follows:

```
(160 AND 6) = 0
(0 AND 6) = 0
(0 AND 6) = 0
(0 AND 6) = 0
(0 AND 6) = 0
(0 AND 6) = 0
(0 AND 6) = 0
(176 AND 6) = 0
```

Comment: `man 1 printf`.

Comment: I added the expected outputs in the question. Basically I just to have bitwise AND between the two nos.

Comment: I don't understand your edit and the script at all. What do you expect `num2` and `num1` to be?

Answer (score 0):

> How to do that correctly?

Just print the output in hexadecimal format:

```
printf "%#018x\n" "$((line & filter))"
```

would output:

```
0x001234560c012345
```

Notes:

- If you want to specify the base inside bash arithmetic expansion, you have to remove the `0x`. So either `$(( 16#${line:2} ))` or just let bash  auto-detect the `0x` prefix and parse the number as hexadecimal automatically.
- The lines `$line=0xC01234567C012345` and `$filter=0x07ffffff0fffffff` in your post are invalid - you can't assign to the result of parameter expansion.
- The `$` to expand variables inside arithmetic expansion are not needed.
- The `%#018x` printf format specifier is equal to `0x%016x`. Note how the result of `#` format specifier is counted to the width of the field.
- The `awk` can't handle such big numbers. With `-M` GNU extension to `awk` you can enable `awk` to use big number library, so than you can do: `awk -M -v line=$line -v filter=$filter '{ printf "0x%016x\n", and(strtonum(line), strtonum(filter)) }' <<<''`